# Gatling where to place JSON files?

Tags: scala, gatling

I'm having issues with loading a JSON file in Gatling. It works with an absolute path but not with a relative. Where should JSON files be stored? I've tried `/home/dev/gatling-charts-highcharts-bundle-2.3.0/user-files/data` but the file could not be found.

Piece of my code:

```
def addCredential(status_code: Option[Seq[Int]], username: Option[String]) = {
        feed(random_user)
            .exec(http("[POST] /users/[user]/credentials")
            .post("/users/%s/credentials".format(username getOrElse "${username}"))
            .body(RawFileBody("credential.json")).asJSON
            .check(status.in(202, 404, 409)))
    }
```

The file `credential.json` can be found if I give the absolute path but this is not optimal because several people use the simulations.

Comment: According to the [docs](https://gatling.io/docs/current/session/feeder/#csv-feeders) the `data` directory is the right place to store your files. Have you tried using a [JSON feeder](https://gatling.io/docs/current/session/feeder/#json-feeders) like `jsonFile("credential.json")` and using a [StringBody](https://gatling.io/docs/2.3/http/http_request/#request-body) with the content of the credential.json?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can configure the folder where the bodies are located in **gatling.conf**.

```
 directory {
     bodies = user-files/bodies           # Folder where bodies are located
 }
```

Then you can put your file in the configured path `/your-project/user-files/bodies/credential.json`.